# Trying to implemen custom number pad for UITextField in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am working on an app where I have a UITableView that has a UITextField in each cell.  The textfield is attached to each row via a custom cell.  Because there is no number only keypad for the iPad, I have to implement my own (I don't have a choice here).  I have created custom buttons for this keyboard inside MainStoryboard, attached these buttons to a view that serves as a custom inputView.  These buttons all call the same method which should enter the value of the label on the button, into the textfield.  Unfortunately, this is not working.  I am implementing the UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{


    NSLog(@"how about here?");
    return YES;

}
```

which unfortunately does not get called when I place the cursor in any of the textfields, and not when I press any of the keys on the keypad, since I don't see any output on my xcode screen.

I attach the custom  keypad to the inputView attribute of each textfield inside my "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method as follows:

```
_cell.textField.inputView = _inputView;
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  I figure implementing the UITextFieldDelegate would be the way to go to accomplish this (which to me appears to be very straight forward), but unfortunately I'm struggling with this.  I have also included a screenshot if it helps.[image]

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Comment: can you also post how you are generating your textfield? It might be possible that you have not set the delegate of the textField (you need to set it to the view controller which implements uitextfieldelegate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make

```
textField.delegate = self
```

or

```
_cell.textField.delegate = self;
```

Hope this works !!!